# Propagation text to be sent in expats' mailing list

Tags: support, site-promotion, community

Once the site gets into public beta, I would like to propagate it in the mailing list of Czech people in France. I can write down a nice smooth propagation text myself, but I'm not sure that it's gonna be as nice and as smooth as it can be.

So I want to ask, is there any such propagation text available? Something that would explain what the site is for and briefly how it works? Any such material or even brief ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sure, I bet we could write something for you in very clear International English, which would be easy to translate. See also [what should our elevator pitch for the site be](http://meta.expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/99/whats-the-elevator-pitch-for-our-site), in which we're trying to make a short, clear summary of the scope and purpose of the site. We could take that, and add a little to it, then all you'd need to do is cover recent questions and you'd have something to send.

Comment: (Also, there will shortly _be_ a newsletter you can get for the site, which you could wrap with the custom text and you'd have something well suited to send off) - I'll take a crack at the propagation text in a bit, if someone doesn't beat me to it.